# How can I pass data between two tablets with a wired connection using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, usb, usbserial

I am building a Flutter application that needs to transmit data through a wired connection between two tablets (Samsung Galaxy Tab S7+). Both tablets will be running the same Flutter application. I can not use any form of wireless connection like WIFI or Bluetooth so I will need to use USB. The data will be something simple like a string. Both tablets should be able to send and receive messages at any time to the other tablet.

I have used the usb_serial package and I am able to see the connection when I plug the tablets together but I can't figure out how to receive messages. https://pub.dev/packages/usb_serial/example

I could also use a USB-C to Ethernet adapter on the tablet if that helps but again there can be no wireless networking.

Is there any way to pass the data between these devices using Flutter?

Comment: Did you successfully open the port?. I have created an app for android(installed on raspberry-pi) and communicate between raspberry and arduino using `usb_serial` package and works.

Comment: what is the result of `await _port!.open();`?